# watson conversation check entity exists

Tags: entity, ibm-watson

I want to check if an entity is part of the users input. 
Example:

```
entities['@PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST']?.contains($variables.tmpEntity)
```

As you can see by this example, the value of the entity`@PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST`
is a variable. I put this at a condition for a node, but this is not working.
If I use a hardcoded string instead of the variable it is working fine.

`entities['@PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST']?.contains('Chart')` works fine
but setting `$variables.tmpEntity` to 'Chart' a and then ask for 
`entities['@PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST']?.contains($variables.tmpEntity)`
is not working.

Can someone tells me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to understand what you are trying to do.But if you want to check whether an entity exist in your input or not you can do it by applying condition on size of that entity.

```
"context":{
"size":"<?@Entity.size()?>"
}
```

now if size is equals to 0 then entity does not exist.

I know this is a longer way but it also tells you how many times does that entity exist in your input.

Comment: Hi, I want to check if a value exists for an entity (@PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST) in the input of the user. The value searched for is determined programmatic so it could have different values like "Chart", "Performance"...Using @Entity.size will not me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used the wrong statement. 
This statement should work:
entities[PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST]?.get($variables.countEntity).value==$variables.$variables.tmpEntity

$variables.countEntity : counter to iterate thru entity array @PRODUKT_INTENT_STOP_LIST to check if an entity value is equal $variables.tmpEntity

Regards